# d3 grouped bar chart creation issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a grouped bar chart using d3 but all the examples i saw have different data format then mine and i am not able to figure out how to draw the chart using my data format.

For example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Here is my data:

```
var data =[
{
  "data": [
    [
      "2016-01-21T01:20:00.000Z",
      1.41818181818182
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T02:28:00.000Z",
      1.90661764705882
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T03:36:00.000Z",
      1.66764705882353
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T04:44:00.000Z",
      1.51691176470588
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T05:52:00.000Z",
      1.40955882352941
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T07:00:00.000Z",
      1.46323529411765
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T08:08:00.000Z",
      1.48308823529412
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T09:16:00.000Z",
      1.89384615384615
    ]
  ],
  "label": "a"
},
{
  "data": [
    [
      "2016-01-21T01:20:00.000Z",
      4.98701298701299
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T02:28:00.000Z",
      5.0
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T03:36:00.000Z",
      4.94852941176471
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T04:44:00.000Z",
      4.91176470588235
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T05:52:00.000Z",
      4.81617647058824
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T07:00:00.000Z",
      5.0
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T08:08:00.000Z",
      4.94117647058824
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T09:16:00.000Z",
      4.96969696969697
    ]
  ],
  "label": "b"
}
];
```

So please help me in creating a grouped bar chart using my data format.

Code of what i have written so far: [CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/S5H7mXUibdhSmA92J0Pi?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
   .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]); //Note this is returning data
      })
```

It should be

```
 .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d[1]); //Note this is returning data
  })
```

You have not made another scale to position the bars as a result of which the bars were coming one on to of the other.

```
var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();
x1.domain(data.map(function(d){return d.label})).rangeRoundBands([0, x.rangeBand()]);
```

Then in the group you will need to give a transform like this to allign the a bar and b bars:

```
  .attr("transform", function(d,i) { 
    var r = parseFloat(x1(d.label));
    if (r == 0){
      r = r-5;
    }
    return "translate(" +  r  + ",0)"; 

  })
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/osTDBv4Dnapd40AFiLz6?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the solution. May i ask why are you subtracting 5? And what if instead of 2 bar data, i give data to create 3 bars, will the code will work in that case also?